# How are POST and GET variables handled in Python?

Tags: python, post, get

In PHP you can just use `$_POST` for POST and `$_GET` for GET (Query string) variables. What's the equivalent in Python?

Comment: Are you writing a CGI script, mod_python, or Django (or other framework) application? The answer hinges on a bit more info...

Comment: can you provide sample code for each of these?

Comment: CGI, mod_python, Django, CherryPy and Pylons aren't code samples.  They're Python Web Frameworks that handle GET and POST.  See http://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks for information.  Your question -- as asked -- cannot be answered.

Answer (score 257, accepted):

suppose you're posting a html form with this:

```
<input type="text" name="username">
```

If using [raw cgi](http://docs.python.org/library/cgi.html):

```
import cgi
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
print form["username"]
```

If using [Django](http://docs.djangoproject.com/), [Pylons](http://pylonshq.com/), [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) or [Pyramid](http://www.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/about):

```
print request.GET['username'] # for GET form method
print request.POST['username'] # for POST form method
```

Using [Turbogears](http://turbogears.org/), [Cherrypy](http://www.cherrypy.org/):

```
from cherrypy import request
print request.params['username']
```

[Web.py](http://webpy.org):

```
form = web.input()
print form.username
```

[Werkzeug](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/):

```
print request.form['username']
```

If using Cherrypy or Turbogears, you can also define your handler function taking a parameter directly:

```
def index(self, username):
    print username
```

[Google App Engine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/introduction):

```
class SomeHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        name = self.request.get('username') # this will get the value from the field named username
        self.response.write(name) # this will write on the document
```

So you really will have to choose one of those frameworks.

Comment: Using `import cgi`, isn't it `print form["username"].value`?

Comment: I am using `Bottle` which I believe uses `wsgi`, could anyone post the equivalent to use in that scenario? The above response is the clearest explanation I have come across, it just doesn't include my scenario.

Comment: FieldStorage is broken in python3, you may experience issues with it.
http://bugs.python.org/issue6234

Comment: Allow me to clarify on my previous comment; this page: http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2013/7/2/the-updated-guide-to-unicode/ better explains it. **Do not use FieldStorage() in python 3 because of encoding issues.**

Comment: For Flask it's a little different: request.args.get('username')

Comment: @NuclearPeon I am facing trouble in python 2.7.6 too. When I print value returned from cgi.FeildStorage, this is what output is FieldStorage(None, None, []). I have posted a full question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38024516/python-cgi-script-for-http-server-post-variables-are-being-received-as-none

Comment: For CGI, `form["username"]` had to be `form.getvalue("username")` for me as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/464087/6243352).

Answer (score 45):

I know this is an old question. Yet it's surprising that no good answer was given.

First of all the question is completely valid without mentioning the framework. The CONTEXT is a PHP language equivalence. Although there are many ways to get the query string parameters in Python, the framework variables are just conveniently populated. In PHP, `$_GET` and `$_POST` are also convenience variables. They are parsed from QUERY_URI and php://input respectively.

In Python, these functions would be `os.getenv('QUERY_STRING')` and `sys.stdin.read()`. Remember to import os and sys modules.

We have to be careful with the word "CGI" here, especially when talking about two languages and their commonalities when interfacing with a web server. 1. CGI, as a protocol, defines the data transport mechanism in the HTTP protocol. 2. Python can be configured to run as a CGI-script in Apache. 3. The CGI module in Python offers some convenience functions.

Since the HTTP protocol is language-independent, and that Apache's CGI extension is also language-independent, getting the GET and POST parameters should bear only syntax differences across languages.

Here's the Python routine to populate a GET dictionary:

```
GET={}
args=os.getenv("QUERY_STRING").split('&')

for arg in args: 
    t=arg.split('=')
    if len(t)>1: k,v=arg.split('='); GET[k]=v
```

and for POST:

```
POST={}
args=sys.stdin.read().split('&')

for arg in args: 
    t=arg.split('=')
    if len(t)>1: k, v=arg.split('='); POST[k]=v
```

You can now access the fields as following:

```
print GET.get('user_id')
print POST.get('user_name')
```

I must also point out that the CGI module doesn't work well. Consider this HTTP request:

```
POST / test.py?user_id=6

user_name=Bob&age=30
```

Using `CGI.FieldStorage().getvalue('user_id')` will cause a null pointer exception because the module blindly checks the POST data, ignoring the fact that a POST request can carry GET parameters too.

Comment: I got this error: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'` using `CGI` with `Python` 2.7

Comment: About the error @candlejack said, try getting the arguments like this `POST.get('user_name', 'default_value')`.

Comment: @GeorgeSiggouroglou The 'default_value' thing solved my issue. Thanks!

Comment: Definitely my favourite answer so far! +1

Comment: QUERY_STRING is not a valid index on Mac

Answer (score 32):

I've found nosklo's answer very extensive and useful! For those, like myself, who might find accessing the raw request data directly also useful, I would like to add the way to do that:

```
import os, sys

# the query string, which contains the raw GET data
# (For example, for http://example.com/myscript.py?a=b&c=d&e
# this is "a=b&c=d&e")
os.getenv("QUERY_STRING")

# the raw POST data
sys.stdin.read()
```

Comment: I am trying to **call a method** in a cgi file. An example url is `http://www.myserver.com/cgi-bin/cgi.py/ThisIsMyMethod`. The following environmental variables are related: `os.environ.get('PATH_INFO')` which gets the method name (eg: /ThisIsMyMethod) and `os.environ.get('SCRIPT_NAME')` which provides the path to the script from the web host's root folder (eg: /cgi-bin/cgi.py). In my case, QUERY_STRING is blank, as I am using POST.

Answer (score 30):

They are stored in the CGI fieldstorage object.

```
import cgi
form = cgi.FieldStorage()

print "The user entered %s" % form.getvalue("uservalue")
```

Comment: -1. there are quite a few representation of the request object, depending on the libs/framework used.

Comment: I'm not sure why you did -1. I mean, what I gave works. Perhaps he is unable to use a framework. ALso, don't most frameworks just use this in the background?

Comment: Was stupid to do -1, I've +1 to balance it, plus I think this is the best method as it returns a sting (which is what's asked for)

Comment: @Liam Not sure why you're getting None, but this post is over 6 years old, so I wouldn't doubt if things have changed.

Comment: @EvanFosmark I am getting None values by using this. When I print value returned from cgi.FeildStorage, this is what output is FieldStorage(None, None, []). I have posted a full question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38024516/python-cgi-script-for-http-server-post-variables-are-being-received-as-none
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It somewhat depends on what you use as a CGI framework, but they are available in dictionaries accessible to the program. I'd point you to the docs, but I'm not getting through to python.org right now.  But [this note on mail.python.org will give you a first pointer](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2008-April/485712.html).  Look at the CGI and URLLIB Python libs for more.

**Update**

Okay, that link busted.  Here's the [basic wsgi ref](https://docs.python.org/2/library/wsgiref.html)

Comment: If you're not ambitious enough to follow a link, I'm not ambitious enough to cut and paste if from the link.

Comment: and now the link is dead and that's why everyone hates answers like this and downvotes them. Congratulations.

Comment: You know, every time I get a comment from someone bitching that a five -- nearly six -- year old answer now has a broken link, without, say, adding a replacement link, I can bet it's someone with rep < 1000.

Comment: If I knew where to go for the replacement link (hint, I didn't because your link didn't work) I wouldn't have been looking this question up.

Comment: You *could* always try the hint about 'CGI and URLLIB python libs' I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Python is only a language, to get GET and POST data, you need a web framework or toolkit written in Python.  Django is one, as Charlie points out, the cgi and urllib standard modules are others.  Also available are Turbogears, Pylons, CherryPy, web.py, mod_python, fastcgi, etc, etc.

In Django, your view functions receive a request argument which has request.GET and request.POST.  Other frameworks will do it differently.

Comment: "to get GET and POST data, you need a web framework or toolkit written in Python" - Simply not true

Comment: I agree with James, if they are written in Python they can clearly be written again to your own preference.

Comment: Ok I am a new comer in python and I thought it can't be possible that I have to use a framework. My question is what is the way?I am not using any framework and I had apache2 serve a python script. It will be nice showing a dead simple way as the usage of $_GET or $_POST in php.

Comment: @JamesTomasino In the context of the question, it is true.