# Python: ways of parsing get/post parameters

Tags: python, post, get, cgi

I'm trying to analyse different ways of Python connection to webserver: cgi, fastcgi, mod_python, WSGI, and Django framework... 
So, how many ways exist to parse get/post parameters in python? Are they differ from one connection to another?

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464040/how-are-post-and-get-variables-handled-in-python). CGI, Django etc. are considered there. But what about fastCGI? Is it the same way as CGI? And mod_python, WSGI?

I take interest in the most usable, 'popular' ways of getting request parameters.
It can be parsing of particular parameter (name=value) or entire query string parsing.

Where I can read about different APIs?
There are so many connection methods and frameworks, so I get confused(

Thanks a lot! Nikolai.

Comment: I found [this tutorial](http://webpython.codepoint.net/), it gave me some answers about mod_python and WSGI. Are they correct? And what about fastCGI? And can I import cgi and use parseqs() in mod_python, for example?

Answer (score 2):

[`urlparse.parseqs[l]()`](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.parse_qs) is used to parse parameters. But you likely won't have to do it yourself since the framework (if you're using one) will handle them.

Comment: Thanks, I saw this method. I take interest in both 'backend' and 'framework' methods. And I don't understand, are these methods vary with different connections.