# I have an HTML file with First name and last name in it. How do i put this data into the file in python

Tags: python, html, cgi

There is an HTML file which takes first name and last name in it. Now  I want that data to be into the file using python. There's something called CGI script, but I am not getting to how should I write.
Moreover I am an newbie. So sorry for asking silly question

here's my HTML code:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>INFORMATION</title>
    </head>
      <body>
        <form action = "/cgi-bin/test.py" method = "post">
            FirstName:
            <input type = "text" name = "firstname" /><br>
            LastName:
            <input type = "text" name = "lastname" /><br>

            <input type = "submit" name = "submit "value = "SUBMIT">
            <input type = "reset" name = "reset" value = "RESET">
            </form>
       </body>
</html>
```

My python code which i wrote is:

```
#!usr/bin/python

form = web.input()
print form.firstname
print form.lastname
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to setup a server that redirects requests to a python script, change the url of the form action to point to that script and then actually write a python script that does what you want.

Have you tried looking into a Web Development framework like [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/)? That might do what you want.

Comment: Ok, cool. Follow the instructions in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/464040/how-are-post-and-get-variables-handled-in-python) then.

Comment: its not working so ...when i run my web server with html page submit click it shows no file found

Answer (score 0):

Change the form action to point to the URL of the Python script you want the data sent to. Then implement your Python script to get the POST variables "firstname" and "lastname". There's an example here: [How are POST and GET variables handled in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464040/how-are-post-and-get-variables-handled-in-python).

Comment: What should i write in the python program. means how can i extract data from html and write in python. i m not getting

Comment: I mean how should i write/put into the file. I know to wite into file for f.write method of FILE. but how do i extract data from html ??

Comment: That linked question shows you exactly what to do. There is nothing here that requires "extracting data from html".

Comment: giving the action doesnot display the result