# Using js XMLHttp Request, post method -How do I get access to the data from the python server side?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I am doing js XMLHttp request using the POST method.  As well I'm sending a parameter when I send
    subjectAPI.send(curs);

This may be basic but just don't know - from the server side, how do I retrieve the parameter data ('curs')??

Comment: Maybe this SO can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/464040/how-are-post-and-get-variables-handled-in-python

Comment: Using what language? Your server is almost certainly not coded in Javascript, and different languages have different methods of parsing the requests.