# Cant get AngularJS's $http.post data in Django

Tags: python, django, angularjs, angularjs-http

I know its a very basic question but after wasting my whole day I am asking this. I am just sending data using following AngularJS code to Django:

```
$http.post('/data/creation', 
                    {
                html: 'a'

            }).
              success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                // this callback will be called asynchronously
                // when the response is available
                  console.log(data);
                  console.log(status);
                  console.log(headers);
                  console.log(config);
              }).
              error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                // or server returns response with an error status.
                  console.log(status);
                  console.log(data);
              });
```

and in django:

```
@csrf_exempt
def snippets_post(request):
    html = False
    css = False
    js = False
    JSONdata = False
    response = "You're looking at the results of question %s."
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            JSONdata = request.POST.get('data', False) # it was [] in actual
        except:
            JSONdata = 'ERROR'

    return HttpResponse(JSONdata)
```

I am getting False as response, **"by replacing data to html in POST.get result is same"**. I don't know whats going wrong here. Can any one help me here on this?

Thanks

Comment: Could you please return a static value and check.. return HttpResponse("post value") ..I am doubting about that URL is hitting this snippet or somewhere?

Comment: Communication is going perfect, I am getting False because POST.get is not able to get 'data' or 'html'. Question is how to get that?

Comment: Please track the request using firebug or chrome network tab by clicking F12 and see if url contains html/data while request processing..if it is there, then problem is in your server side code...

Comment: Off course, data is going and checked, its some python/django issue, some parsing etc. that I am missing here, but can't say.

Comment: Remove all the lines and simply try like this request.POST['data'] ...Check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/464040/how-are-post-and-get-variables-handled-in-python

Comment: actually I tried that before, both are same except one returns False and other gives Error. that's why added try catch, but didn't worked either.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64266/discussion-between-asik-and-arslan-rafique).

Comment: Thanks @Asik, I solved that mystery. Appreciate you help =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, when we send data from AngularJs using $http's POST, it sends the data with the **content-type = "application/json"** to the server. And Django doesn't understand that format. And so you can't get the sent data.

Solution is to change the content-type header by using following config:

```
    app.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
}]);
```

Comment: Interesting! Glad to know about this. thanks for informing :)

Comment: Thanks, this also applies to the Turbogears framework