# Python: Is there a way to us GET like in PHP, when running the script?

Tags: python, get

In PHP I use this for script.php?data=something:

```
$data = $_GET['data'];
echo $data;
```

Is there a way to do the same in Python when I start the script? Or how can I manage to start a script multiple times with different values?

Comment: Did you even tried to research about it? It doesn't seem like something hard to find out.

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/464040/how-are-post-and-get-variables-handled-in-python