# running python-scripts on MAMP 3.5 on mac osx 10.11

Tags: javascript, python, macos, mamp

I try to run a simple "helloWorld" python-snippet on the new MAMP 3.5, because may old xampp got problems with the update to mac osx el capitan.

The MAMP-Documentation says that mod_wsgi, actual python and mod_python is embeded. However if i place my test.py in the htdocs and try to contact it via a JavaScript-function (ajax.POST) it seems the script is found but as result i only receive the text of my test.py in the firebug-console back. Somehow it seems the python script is not executed.

headline in test.py is `#!/bin/usr/python`, i also tried to place the test.py in the MAMP/cgi-bin-directory or to use other existing python-paths (MAMP/"which python") Does anyone have an idea? Below are my two snippets:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $("button").click(function(){

                var myValue = $("input:text").val();
                console.log(myValue);

                $.ajax({
                     type: "POST",
                     url: "test.py",
                     data: { myPy: myValue},

                     success: function(data) {   
                        console.log("This is my result: ", data);             
                    }        
                });
            });
       });
    </script>
```

This is test.py:

```
    #!/bin/usr/python

    def myjsfunction (myPy):
         return (myPy)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem and I have managed to solve by doing the following:

Disclosure:

- Currently running MAMP 3.5
- Python 2.7

Steps:

1. Add the following line in the httpd.conf file (MAMP/conf/Apache/httpd.conf) within the  tag as shown below:

Line to be added:

```
Options FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
```

Section to be added in:

```
    <Directory />
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Options FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
    </Directory>
```

2. Create a .cgi python file as follows (this file should have the .cgi extension btw, and you should call it as such from your ajax call):

   ```
    #!/usr/bin/python
    print 'Content-type: text/html\n\n'
    import cgi
    response = cgi.FieldStorage()
    print response["myPy"].value
   ```

That should give you the output you wanted. If you don't want to use raw CGI, check out this post for other options for the python script (i.e. django).

[How are POST and GET variables handled in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464040/how-are-post-and-get-variables-handled-in-python)

Hope this helps.