# Handling web links in Python

Tags: python

I have some links stored in a file which looks like this:

```
http://r14---sn-p5qlsnss.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?itag=22&id=o-AOtM1kWozUiJKP2ENWH989ZIfJaZNPVvXTrBkXx40lG5&key=yt6&ip=159.253.144.86&lmt=1480060612064057&dur=1047.870&mv=m&source=youtube&ms=au&ei=DtN8WLfwFsKb1gKXho6YDw&expire=1484597102&mn=sn-p5qlsnss&mm=31&ipbits=0&nh=IgpwcjAzLmlhZDA3KgkxMjcuMC4wLjE&initcwndbps=4717500&mt=1484575249&pl=24&signature=1ECAB2B56C30CBF760721A1A26A7E80963DB36B8.6336B2C9C41DB53C8FA1D2A037793275F57C4825&ratebypass=yes&mime=video%2Fmp4&upn=tUcEt34Qe6c&sparams=dur%2Cei%2Cid%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cnh%2Cpl%2Cratebypass%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&title=600ft+UFO+Crash+Site+Discovered+On+Mars%21+11%2F23%2F16
```

At the end of the link we have the video's title. I want to read this link from a file and get the video's title in a proper format (with those '+' and '%' signs properly resolved). How do I do that?

I cannot use `raw cgi` as [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/464977/5460216) since the link is read from a file and not submitted by a form. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's super convenient **[urllib.parse.parse_qs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.parse_qs)** for python 3, but if you're using python 2, you might have to dig out the title string first.

```
import urllib

url = 'http://r14---sn-p5qlsnss.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?itag=22&id=o-AOtM1kWozUiJKP2ENWH989ZIfJaZNPVvXTrBkXx40lG5&key=yt6&ip=159.253.144.86&lmt=1480060612064057&dur=1047.870&mv=m&source=youtube&ms=au&ei=DtN8WLfwFsKb1gKXho6YDw&expire=1484597102&mn=sn-p5qlsnss&mm=31&ipbits=0&nh=IgpwcjAzLmlhZDA3KgkxMjcuMC4wLjE&initcwndbps=4717500&mt=1484575249&pl=24&signature=1ECAB2B56C30CBF760721A1A26A7E80963DB36B8.6336B2C9C41DB53C8FA1D2A037793275F57C4825&ratebypass=yes&mime=video%2Fmp4&upn=tUcEt34Qe6c&sparams=dur%2Cei%2Cid%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cnh%2Cpl%2Cratebypass%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&title=600ft+UFO+Crash+Site+Discovered+On+Mars%21+11%2F23%2F16'

title = url[url.rfind('&title=') + 7:]
print urllib.unquote_plus(title)
```

**Note:** thanks to [bereal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/770830/bereal) for pointing out [parse_qs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.parse_qs) is also available in python 2, so just:

```
import urlparse
print urlparse.parse_qs(url)['title'][0]

'600ft UFO Crash Site Discovered On Mars! 11/23/16'
```

Comment: [`parse_qs`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.parse_qs) is there since 2.6, just the module has changed.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`urllib.parse.parse_qs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.parse_qs) and give it the string:

```
In [17]: urllib.parse.parse_qs(s)
Out[17]: 
{'dur': ['1047.870'],
 'ei': ['DtN8WLfwFsKb1gKXho6YDw'],
 'expire': ['1484597102'],
 'http://r14---sn-p5qlsnss.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?itag': ['22'],
[.. and so on ..]
 'source': ['youtube'],
 'sparams': ['dur,ei,id,initcwndbps,ip,ipbits,itag,lmt,mime,mm,mn,ms,mv,nh,pl,ratebypass,source,upn,expire'],
 'title': ['600ft UFO Crash Site Discovered On Mars! 11/23/16'],
 'upn': ['tUcEt34Qe6c']}

In [18]: urllib.parse.parse_qs(s)["title"][0]
Out[18]: '600ft UFO Crash Site Discovered On Mars! 11/23/16'
```

Answer (score 1):

[Purl](https://github.com/codeinthehole/purl) can fit your needs:

```
import purl

u = purl.URL('http://r14---sn-p5qlsnss.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?itag=22&id=o-AOtM1kWozUiJKP2ENWH989ZIfJaZNPVvXTrBkXx40lG5&key=yt6&ip=159.253.144.86&lmt=1480060612064057&dur=1047.870&mv=m&source=youtube&ms=au&ei=DtN8WLfwFsKb1gKXho6YDw&expire=1484597102&mn=sn-p5qlsnss&mm=31&ipbits=0&nh=IgpwcjAzLmlhZDA3KgkxMjcuMC4wLjE&initcwndbps=4717500&mt=1484575249&pl=24&signature=1ECAB2B56C30CBF760721A1A26A7E80963DB36B8.6336B2C9C41DB53C8FA1D2A037793275F57C4825&ratebypass=yes&mime=video%2Fmp4&upn=tUcEt34Qe6c&sparams=dur%2Cei%2Cid%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cnh%2Cpl%2Cratebypass%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&title=600ft+UFO+Crash+Site+Discovered+On+Mars%21+11%2F23%2F16')
print(u.query_param('title'))
```

Answer (score 0):

use `urlparse.parse_qs`:

```
try:
    from urlparse import urlparse           # for python2
except:
    from urllib import parse as urlparse    # for python3

rv = urlparse.parse_qs(link)
title = rv['title'][0]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import urllib
a = "http://r14---sn-p5qlsnss.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?itag=22&id=o-AOtM1kWozUiJKP2ENWH989ZIfJaZNPVvXTrBkXx40lG5&key=yt6&ip=159.253.144.86&lmt=1480060612064057&dur=1047.870&mv=m&source=youtube&ms=au&ei=DtN8WLfwFsKb1gKXho6YDw&expire=1484597102&mn=sn-p5qlsnss&mm=31&ipbits=0&nh=IgpwcjAzLmlhZDA3KgkxMjcuMC4wLjE&initcwndbps=4717500&mt=1484575249&pl=24&signature=1ECAB2B56C30CBF760721A1A26A7E80963DB36B8.6336B2C9C41DB53C8FA1D2A037793275F57C4825&ratebypass=yes&mime=video%2Fmp4&upn=tUcEt34Qe6c&sparams=dur%2Cei%2Cid%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cnh%2Cpl%2Cratebypass%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&title=600ft+UFO+Crash+Site+Discovered+On+Mars%21+11%2F23%2F16"
b = a.split('=')[-1]
print urllib.unquote_plus(b)
```