# How to get data from FieldStorage?

Tags: python, python-2.7, cgi

```
form= cgi.FieldStorage()
print form
```

Prints: `FieldStorage(None, None, 'age=10&name=joe')`.

How do I get the data from that form?

I can't use `form[FieldKey]`, because there is no field key.

`form['age']` returns a blank string

I'm using Python 2.7.

Comment: Try `print form.keys()` to see the actual keys for that FieldStorage object,and proceed from there.

Comment: @Bill Bell Error: "not indexable". It's not an array.

Comment: Can you show us more of your code. FieldStorage should expose a method called `keys`.

Comment: form= cgi.FieldStorage()  / print form.keys() -> Error: "not indexable"

Answer (score 2):

This happens when FieldStorage parses "plain" POST data, as opposed to a form for example. If the content-type of the HTTP request is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` however, it will know what to do.

This is the HTML file that has a single send button, once it is clicked, the name and age data are sent to the proc.py script, after the header is set to what the Python CGI library likes.

```html
<html><body>
<button type="button" onclick="sendData()">Send</button>
<div id="content">No reponse from script yet.</div>
<script>
function sendData() {
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
    };
    http.open('POST', '/cgi-bin/proc.py', true);
    http.setRequestHeader('content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    http.send('age=10&name=joe');
}
</script>
</body></html>
```

And proc.py spits these value back:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import cgi
data = cgi.FieldStorage()
print 'Content-type: text/html\n'
print data['name'].value
print '<br />'
print data['age'].value
```

Comment: Thank you for answering a question I asked more than 1 year ago, and which I never solved. Next time I work on that project I will try your solution, and get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: fheshwfq
Update: I am back into that project. The Ajax code _does_ use  http.setRequestHeader('content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
So, I really don't know what's going on.
I just wanted to update you and thank you once more.

Answer (score 2):

Other answers have explained why there was a problem with the request and how to fix it, but I think it might be helpful to better understand the `FieldStorage` object so you can recover from a bad request.

I was mostly able to duplicate your state using this:

```py
from cgi import FieldStorage
from StringIO import StringIO

f = FieldStorage(
    fp=StringIO("age=10&name=joe"), 
    headers={"content-length": 15, "content-type": "plain/text"}, 
    environ={"REQUEST_METHOD": "POST"}
)

print(f) # FieldStorage(None, None, 'age=10&name=joe')
```

This will fail as expected:

```py
f["age"] # TypeError: not indexable
f.keys() # TypeError: not indexable
```

So `FieldStorage` didn't parse the query string because it didn't know it should, but you can make `FieldStorage` manually parse it:

```py
f.fp.seek(0) # we reset fp because FieldStorage exhausted it
# if f.fp.seek(0) fails we can also do this:
# f.fp = f.file
f.read_urlencoded()

f["age"] # 10
f.keys() # ["age", "name"]
```

If you ever need to get the original body from `FieldStorage`, you can get it from the `FieldStorage.file` property, the `file` property gets set when `FieldStorage` parses what it thinks is a plain body:

```py
f.file.read() # "age=10&name=joe"
```

Hope this helps other fellow searchers who stumble on this question in the future.

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```py
import cgi

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
print form.getvalue("age")
```

as described in the more general thread [How are POST and GET variables handled in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464040/how-are-post-and-get-variables-handled-in-python/464087#464087)