# how to capture post request in python script

Tags: php, python

I'm making an application which sends an `POST` request using ajax to a python script. I'm new to python and doesn't know much about it. 
As in PHP we do something like this to get a value from post request.

```
$val = $_POST['data'];
```

How to do this in python? any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: There are hundreds of tutorials on this. Google!!

Comment: i searched. But didn't found anything useful. can you share any URL please?

Answer (score 1):

You can get that using [raw cgi](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cgi.html)

For example:

```
import cgi
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
print form["username"]
```

Everything is explained really well [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464040/how-are-post-and-get-variables-handled-in-python)