# How to handle complicated input form in Python according PHP approach?

Tags: php, python, python-2.7

I have got the following HTML form with several complicated input elements:

```
<input type="text" name="images[1]">
<input type="text" name="images[2]">
<input type="text" name="video[1]">
<input type="text" name="video[2]">
```

When I talk about cimplicated inputs I mean sophisticated name of elements:

```
name="images[1]"
```

Where `images` is indicate group of input and `[1]` number or identificator of input.

Using PHP approach of handling form It can be achieved like:

```
if(isset($_POST['images'])) {
    foreach($_POST['images'] as $index) { // $key
         echo $_POST['images'][$index]; // or key
    }
}
```

How to reproduce this in Python?

Comment: This is the similar question, but a bit differently, because I have key inside brackets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it depends if you are using a python framework (django, Flask, ...) or not.
if you are using a framework, you must read its docs. for example with django, you can handle form element by request.POST['images'].

you can read [How are POST and GET variables handled in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464040/how-are-post-and-get-variables-handled-in-python)

Comment: I use Flask framework

Comment: it's cool then. it's same as Django.

Comment: you just need to import request. and then request.post['images']. hope it can help you... Tell me if it not work

Comment: You can also find another way to do it if you read Flask documentation:  http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/.  for example : @app.route('/route_dest', methods=['POST'])
def handle_method():
    images_list = request.form['images']

Answer (score 0):

It is easy with  HTMLParser.

Take a look at this example.

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser
from htmlentitydefs import name2codepoint

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        print "Start tag:", tag
        for attr in attrs:
            print "     attr:", attr

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        print "End tag  :", tag

    def handle_data(self, data):
        print "Data     :", data

    def handle_comment(self, data):
        print "Comment  :", data

    def handle_entityref(self, name):
        c = unichr(name2codepoint[name])
        print "Named ent:", c

    def handle_decl(self, data):
        print "Decl     :", data

parser = MyHTMLParser()

parser.feed('<input type="text" name="images[1]">')
```

Than you have

```
python a1.py
Start tag: input
     attr: ('type', 'text')
     attr: ('name', 'images[1]')
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, the OP asks about handling a posted form/data, not how to parse HTML.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson You are right,I  haven't pay attention.

Comment: I use Flask framework