# How to get post variable value in Python?

Tags: python, http, post, server

I have my own server and wanna shift it from PHP to Python.
I've searched answers for my question - nothing.

How to get value of `POST` variable which come from client as param?

If I wanna do it by PHP I just can write:

```
$value = $_POST['key'];
```

How to do similar thing by Python?
Sorry for my grammar mistakes.
Thank you.

Comment: Are you any python framework? django, flask?

Comment: No. Started to learn Python recently. I have question not about topic: what the hell is that 3 answers in the bottom???

Comment: The easiest way - using CGI interface [cgi](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/cgi.html). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464040/how-are-post-and-get-variables-handled-in-python